# Symfony 6 : can't get collection in custom FormType

Tags: symfony

I have two entities, **Formation** and **Theme**. A **Theme** can have many **Formation** and **Formation** can belong to many **Theme**. Inside the add form for Formation, I would like to display a select of themes that looks like the image below
[image]

I created a custom FormType called **SearchableEntityType** but in this latter, I can't get the themes. When I `dd($form->getdata())`, it's empty. What do I miss ? Thanks for any help.

Here is the code of Entity/Formation.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Formation;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class FormationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('label')
            ->add('themes' , SearchableEntityType::class, [
                'class' => Theme::class
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Formation::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Entity/Theme.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Theme;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ThemeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('label')
            ->add('color')
            ->add('shortDescription')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Theme::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Form/FormationType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Formation;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class FormationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('label')
            ->add('themes' , SearchableEntityType::class, [
                'class' => Theme::class
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Formation::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Form/SearchableEntityType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Theme;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\View\ChoiceView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class SearchableEntityType extends AbstractType
{
  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setRequired('class');
    $resolver->setDefaults([
      'compound' => false,
      'multiple' => true
    ]);
  }

  public function getBlockPrefix() {
    return 'choice';
  }

  public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options) {

    dd($form);
    
    $view->vars['expanded'] = false;
    $view->vars['placeholder'] = null;
    $view->vars['placeholder_in_choices'] = false;
    $view->vars['multiple'] = true;
    $view->vars['preferred_choices'] = $this->choices($form->getData());
    $view->vars['choices'] = [];
    $view->vars['choice_translation_domain'] = false;
    $view->vars['full_name'] .= '[]';
  }

  private function choices(Collection $value) {

;    return $value
      ->map(fn ($d) => new ChoiceView($d, (string)$d->getId(), (string)$d))
      ->toArray();
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use `entity type` instead of `SearchableEntityType` with option `multiple => true`

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to keep this custom Type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your current `SearchableEntityType`, I don't think it's necessary at all.

You could just use symfony `EntityType` and configure it like your `SearchableEntityType`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Formation;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class FormationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('label')
            ->add('themes', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Theme::class,
                'multiple' => true,
                'choice_label' => 'label',
                'label' => 'Thèmes',
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Formation::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And if you want to use optgroup to have a better display you can look into [group_by](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#group-by) to choose a way to define a group name for each option.